# Problem with disabled button style in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate, app.xaml

I use bellow style in App.xaml file. I want my buttons(SendCommandBtn) have #5e95a7 color when they are enabled with no rounded border and some other styles.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="SendCommandBtn">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#5e95a7"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                    <Border CornerRadius="0"  BorderThickness="0"  Height="28" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f2f2f2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="No"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#5e95a7"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"  x:Key="NormalBtn">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#5e95a7"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#5e95a7"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                    <Border CornerRadius="0"  BorderThickness="0" Background="#5e95a7" Height="28" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now when I have below button:

```
 <Button Name="BtnSIM2" Content=" SIM 2" Grid.Column="2" Click="BtnSIM2_Click" Style="{DynamicResource SendCommandBtn}"></Button>
```

when the button is enable, the background color is transparent and the foreground is white.
When the button is disable again the background is transparent and foreground is Red.
Can any one help me to understand what is wrong with my style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have replaced the control template, therefore you have to change the background of Border that is your "main control" now.
To do so, set the name for your Border inside and change the color of that border instead like this(by targeting that border by its name):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="SendCommandBtn">
   ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                <Border CornerRadius="0"  BorderThickness="0"  Height="28" Margin="0,0,10,0" x:Name="ButtonBorder" >
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="#f2f2f2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="No"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="#5e95a7"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="#fff"/>
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="Hand"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you dear Martin Ch